# How to create property with condition / dynamic foreground color?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a simple text field in a subreport.

**Goal:** Apply *"propertyExpression"* for *"Forecolor"* only when the parameter "evenRow" is ***1***

Following does not work but I gave it a try...

```
<textField>
  <reportElement key="" mode="Transparent" x="108" y="1" width="76" height="13">
    <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.style.forecolor">
        <![CDATA[$P{evenRow} == 1 ? $P{colorZebra1_text} : ""]]>
    </propertyExpression>
  </reportElement>
  <textElement><font fontName="SansSerif" size="8"/></textElement>
  <textFieldExpression>"Text"</textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

**Context**: The parent report calls this! subreport which contains the textfield multiple times (illustrated in attached image). Each time it is called the parent report sends the parameter *"evenRow"* as either 1 or 0...

```
//snipped from parent report to show that "evenRow" is 1 or 0
($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue() % 2 == 0 ?   1 :    0)
```

**Question:** How can I create a propertyExpression for the dynamic "Forecolor" that only comes to effect when my parameter *"evenRow"* is set to ***1*** ?

[image]

*Note:* I am aware I could use [conditional styles](http://community.jaspersoft.com/blog/change-font-color-based-condition-jasper-ireport-work-out-styles) -> The problem with styles in general is that they are never dynamic, i.e. I would have to create 1 style for every single color that 'could' be set ...and because the color can be set to whatever hex value this is not an option.

Comment: The parameter is passed to this "subreport". Because it is a subreport it is called multiple times. Each time the "parent" report knows whether this is an ODD or EVEN subreport call and hence passes the parameter EVENROW (1 or 0) ..I have updated my question. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concept of using *net.sf.jasperreports.style.forecolor* is working well with *propertyExpression* at practice.

#### Single report with parameters

Here is small template with parameters used at *propertyExpression*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Style forecolor" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="NoDataSection" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <parameter name="color" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["#E3106B"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="isApplyColor" class="java.lang.Boolean">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[true]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="DEFAULT_COLOR" class="java.lang.String" >
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["#000000"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="211" y="39" width="100" height="30" uuid="4af3eb91-2334-40fe-a77a-45378fe93210">
                    <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.style.forecolor"><![CDATA[$P{isApplyColor} ? $P{color} : $P{DEFAULT_COLOR}]]></propertyExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Text Field"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

The output result generated at *JSS* looks like this:

[image: Preview at JSS]

I used *"#000000"* (*black*) as default color.

Looks like you need to check and fix the value of *$P{evenRow}*

#### Sample with subreport and master report.

I used subreport with parameters at *propertyExpression* like at first example. This report is using "external" parameter, but there is no difference - it is just a parameter

Subreport's *jrxml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Subreport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="NoDataSection" columnWidth="595" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <parameter name="color" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["#E3106B"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="DEFAULT_COLOR" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["#000000"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="evenRow" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <title>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="130" y="0" width="100" height="20">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.style.forecolor"><![CDATA[$P{evenRow} == 0 ? $P{color} : $P{DEFAULT_COLOR}]]></propertyExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Text Field"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="20" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["evenRow: " + $P{evenRow}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

The 2nd *textField* is just for checking value of *$P{evenRow}*.

The design is very simple:

[image: Design at JSS]

The main report is using this subreport

The *jrxml* of master report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Master" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="10 empty rows"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="130" y="0" width="200" height="20"/>
                <subreportParameter name="evenRow">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[($V{REPORT_COUNT}  % 2 == 0 ?  1 :  0)]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource()]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["Subreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

The *textField* is used for showing row number.

The desing looks like:

[image: The master report at JSS]

The output result at JSS:

[image: Preview at JSS]

Comment: Nice answer, I see they are available since version 4.8 (I continued to ignore'em)

Comment: Works. thank you! (Could've sworn I have tried that hmmm). Result: http://i.imgur.com/mTUif9B.png --- Any idea how I could also have the conditional style for a line? I have tried --- https://jsfiddle.net/6e0uv09p/2/

Answer (score 1):

I would use html [markup](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/markup/) or [styled text](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/styledtext/) to achieve dynamic color on the basis of expression.

```
"<font color='"  + ($P{evenRow}.equals("1") ? $P{colorZebra1_text} : "#000000") + "'>Hello world</font>"
```

## Full example

**jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="ParameterForeground" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="18af9727-d961-4a87-ad3b-c7f64aa36f0d">
    <parameter name="evenRow" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="colorZebra1_text" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="330" height="30" uuid="78773d07-454d-4168-ac36-1351e6b278c1"/>
                <textElement markup="html"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["<font color='"  + ($P{evenRow}.equals("1") ? $P{colorZebra1_text} : "#000000") + "'>Hello world</font>"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

**Result**

[image: output]

<sup>The parameter `evenRow` probably would be better of as `java.lang.Integer` class, but since you are using `equals`, I presume you have defined it as `java.lang.String`, if `Integer` the expression would be `$P{evenRow}==1`</sup>

Comment: Very nice! That works. I wonder if there is a way to have a "conditional parameterExpression". Result: http://i.imgur.com/K0oGXeb.png

Comment: Petter. How would I do that for a report element (line)?:)  ---- <line>
    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="110" y="15" width="602" height="1" forecolor="#???--DYNAMIC HERE---???" />
    <graphicElement>
     <pen lineWidth="0.1" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#999999"/>
    </graphicElement>
   </line>

Comment: Just saw: Any pattern setting is lost when I set the markup to html. Can't do that. So I need another way!